# Remove a folder with the same name as an environment variable

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, filenames, quoting, rm

I was messing around with a log4j properties file and accidently made a folder with the following text `${foo}` however I also have an environment variable named `foo` that points to a folder so thus if I do `rm -rf "${foo}"` it removes the folder `$foo` is pointing to, instead of the folder `${foo}`. How can I specify to delete the folder in my current directory using a relative path instead of deleting the folder the environment variable points to?

Here is the layout to better help understand

`$foo` = `/home/user/bar`

`${foo}` = `/home/user/${foo}`

Comment: What is content of `$foo`?

Comment: @cuonglm the content of `$foo` is a folder called `bar` so if you entered `$foo` and did tab complete it would come up as `/home/user/bar`

Comment: Use single quotes.

Comment: @muru so like this `'${foo}'`?

Comment: @jgr208 if the folder is named `${foo}`, yep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String interpolation causes this. There are a number of ways to selectively prevent this from happening.
The bash hackers wiki has some [good examples](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting), though the specifics may vary if you're not actually using bash.

In short, you can prevent interpolation with single quotes, or you can escape the characters.

```
[me:~/work]$ export foo=bar
[me:~/work]$ echo $foo
bar
[me:~/work]$ echo "\${foo} is set to ${foo}"
${foo} is set to bar
```